# Is it possible to use the AND clause in a MYSQL JOIN statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im currently using PDO to make my database queries, i find that that the query doesnt run when i append the "AND IFC.location= :location" section of the query, is the problem arising from using an AND clause while im already using the query to JOIN two tables? (the 'tables' table and the 'IFC' table)

```
$location= '1';

echo "<pre>";
$sql="SELECT name from IFC,tables
      WHERE IFC.tablename=tables.id AND IFC.location=:location
      ORDER BY Numopinions DESC 
      ";
$stmt= $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":location", $location);

if($stmt->execute())
{
    $rows = $stmt-> fetchAll();
    print_r($rows);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Your query should work, but the proper syntax would use explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM IFC JOIN
     tables
     ON IFC.tablename = tables.id AND IFC.location = :location
ORDER BY Numopinions DESC;
```

Is there a reason you think your query does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes AND can be used in joins also. If you think your statement is not working, just try to use without prepare statement and see the result.